# iTerm2 MacVim color is darker than in GUI MacVim

Tags: vim, terminal, vi, macvim, iterm2

I installed MacVim and placed it in my Applications folder. I want to also be able to use my MacVim inside iTerm2 so I would launch MacVim using

```
mvim -v
```

This opens the MacVim inside iTerm2 successfully. However, no matter what colorscheme I apply, there is always a color mismatch between iTerm2 MacVim and GUI MacVim. ***The color inside iTerm2 MacVim is always slightly darker.***

I checked the following settings:
- **[iTerm2]** Report terminal type: xterm-256color
- **[GUI]** set t_Co=256

[image: iTerm2 [right] and GUI [left]]

Comment: This is a known iTerm issue. You should upgrade both iTerm and MacVim and read `:help termguicolors`.

Comment: It didn't help unfortunately. I updated both MacVim (Version 8.0) and Iterm2 (Version 3.0.12)